# Probability - Catching a fish

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I'm not sure I'm understanding this question,

If the probability of me to catch a fish is 0.8, what is the minimal tries must I make so that the probability of catching a fish on at least once is at least 0.9?

I thought maybe I need to do here some kind of probability tree? that catching fish and me catching fish is -> 0.8*0.9 = 0.72, and at least one time means to use the binomial distribution? I'm not sure cause I don't have a limit to choose my options from here.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to say, "If the probability of my catching a fish on one try is $.8$, how nay tries must I make so that the probability of catching a fish on at least one of the is at least $.9$?"  If so, consider how many tries you must make so that the probability of *not* catching a fish on any one of them is $\leq .1$.

Comment: +1 to @saulspatz for being able to fish out the meaning in the OP stmt :)

Comment: Probability of **not catching** a fish in one try is $0.2=1-0.8$, in 2 tries $(1-0.8)^2$ and so on ... probability of catching a at least one fish is $1 - $ probability of catching no fish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Try to use this property
$$P(\text{x to happen})=1-P(\text{x not to happen})$$

Thus, if the probability of catching a fish in one try is $p$ then

- the probability of not catching a fish in one try is $1-p$
- the probability of not catching a fish in $2$ tries is $(1-p)^2$
- ...
- the probability of not catching a fish in $n$ tries is $(1-p)^n$

Then the probability to catch at least one fish in $n$ tries is 
$$1-(1-p)^n$$
Now, the question is to find minimal $n$ such that $$1-(1-0.8)^n\geq 0.9$$